# Is there a Non-blocking emgu ImageViewer call?

Tags: c#, computer-vision, emgucv

I want to show images of my emgu processing while the program is running. Currently, if I use the emgu ImageViewer the program stops and waits until I close the viewer.
Is a way to update an emgu ImageViewer with a new image?
Or alternatively, is there a way to not have the program wait for the user to close a window before continuing?

Thanks in advance!
Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In emgu cv you can call the

```
CvInvoke.cvShowImage("window showing a picture", Picture)
```

function where picture is an instance of

```
Emgu.CV.Image<Tcolor, Tdepth>
```

It wont block your program.
If you want to show the picture with modification done over time use the same function with the same window name(param 1) here the string "window showing a picture" .

Hope it will help =)

Comment: Works beautifully if I also add a CvInvoke.cvWaitKey(1) afterwards.